# Language folder

Tags: codeigniter, internationalization

I’ve just upgraded my Codeigniter from 1.7.2 to 2.1.0. And I noticed the language folder became longer from “en” to “english”.

Is there a way to change the language folder back to short name?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CodeIgniter documentation tells you loading languages is done by the following command.

```
$this->lang->load('filename', 'language');
```

Where the `filename` would be [name] (file is called [name]_lang.php) and `language` would be the name of the folder.

So renaming the english folder to `en` and then load it trough the command like:

```
$this->lang->load('filename', 'en');
```

[CodeIgniter Documentation: Language Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html)